# What are the benefits of using smaller registers, e.g. al vs eax / rax

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction

I noticed that GHC's code generator does not currently output assembly that uses any of the lower machine registers like `al`. Even byte-size operations are implemented using `rax` on 64 bit and `eax` on 32 bit machines. GCC, however, frequently makes use of these smaller registers.

**Are there any real performance benefits of using small registers** like `al`?

---

One suggestion I've heard so far is that the opcode for `inc al` is smaller than `inc rax` (but not smaller than `inc eax`). Are there other, non-performance considerations why to use small registers?

Comment: Some of the shift instructions take only `cl`. In that case, you're *required* to use a small register.

Comment: In addition to smaller encoding, some instructions are simply faster with 8 bits than 32.

Comment: I think the answer as everyone has been implying is in the encoding.  I wouldnt use GCC output as a reference necessarily.  The intel documentation can/will show the encoding for various instructions and you can see for example if you want to add two small numbers you dont necessarily need 64 bits worth of immediates when maybe 16 will do.  Likewise one byte of opcode may do per instruction rather than two or more.  Beyond the binary fetching real estate bandwidth, number of instructions and size of each, then it becomes microcode issues which are hidden to us.

Comment: [64 bit assembly, when to use smaller size registers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6577458/995714)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the 64-bit registers (rxx) on x86-64 requires opcode-prefixes. Thus the instructions are longer, taking more space in memory and the instruction cache. I don't know if it also slows down decoding.
The code-size could hurt performance if the bigger code is used in a loop that doesn't fit into the L1 instruction cache.

Answer (score 4):

If you only use al for an 8-bit value, it leaves ah free for a second one.

Loading ax vs. rax *may* offer memory bandwidth advantages.  However, it could also possibly cause problems too.  Gotta be careful there.

Comment: Subregisters cannot be renamed, which cramps the processor's ability to parallelize operations. Most modern compilers will zero-extend bytes to fill the target register to avoid the false dependency.